# Multiple concatenation in MySQL query and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, group-concat

Hey guys still very new to C# and am very lost.

I have two drop down list `ddlcountry`(Country) and `DdPetPist`(Specie) the country selection populates the Specie list with the specie avalible in the country selected.

**code bellow**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                MySqlCommand cd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Country) FROM Animals", cs); 
                cs.Open();
                MySqlDataReader ddlCountry = cd2.ExecuteReader();
                ddlcountry.DataSource = ddlCountry;
                ddlcountry.DataValueField = "Country";
                ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Country";
                ddlcountry.DataBind();
                cs.Close();
                cs.Dispose();
            }
        }

protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ddlcountry.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE Country ='{0}'", ddlcountry.Text), cs);
                cs.Open();
                MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
                DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
                DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
                DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
                DdPetPist.DataBind();
                cs.Close();
                cs.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

This works very well and I am happy with it, although I am in the process of protecting it from sql injection.

**The problem**

I am know trying to print Information out into two labels with two query's, this I am having problems with. so far my label will print out information such as pet price and stock amounts. but I cant seem to get the query's to adjust with the different country selection.
I have been at this for a few days now and any help will be fantastic as I am very new to C# and still learning.

Label code and query's(not changing with different country selection)

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
            string selection_stock = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
            string petPrice = string.Empty;
            string available = string.Empty;

            MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price), cs);
            MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_stock), cs);

            cs.Open();
            petPrice = Convert.ToString(cd_price.ExecuteScalar());
            available = Convert.ToString(cd_available.ExecuteScalar());
            cs.Close();

            PetPrice.Text = String.Format("Minimum Donation For A {0}  Is £{1}.", selection_price, petPrice);
            Availble.Text = String.Format("{0}'s Avalible {1} In Your Country.", selection_stock, available);
        }
```

Comment: do you tables named : `<countryname>_Animals`?

Comment: not any more ive made one table with the country in, so i know i need to change {0}_Animal part but im not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't put `single quote` over `selection_price` value.
single quote is only required for `varchar`(String) types

**Replace this:**

```
MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM {0}_Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price), cs);
```

**With this:**

```
  MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM {0}_Animals WHERE Specie ={1}", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price), cs);
```

**Solution 2:**
you need to use the `SelectedItem` property of `ComboBox`.

Replace these 2 queries:

```
MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_price), cs);
MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}'", ddlcountry.Text, selection_stock), cs);
```

**With following 2 queries:**

```
MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Specie_Price FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}'", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection_price), cs);
MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}'", ddlcountry..SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection_stock), cs);
```

Comment: What are these "Turkey_Animals" tables?

Comment: No they were but ive made all Animals in one table now with a column for country's before it was UK_Animals, but now the UK and France so fourth are all in the table animals

Comment: @Beep : check my edited answer with section `Solution 2` hope it helps you :)

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi the label prints, but it dose not change with the selection of different country. for example there are 9 dogs available in UK when I chose Germany it still gets the information from the UK not the information from Germany

Comment: @Beep: so now from your queries it will always fetch infromation from Animals table irrespective of the combobox item you choose, give me your Animal table names asper countrywise .

Comment: I have one table with Specie | Specie_Price | Stock | Country, the first drop down uses country column the second shows all Species in the selected country. the label should show stock and Specie_Price for the selected country

Comment: @Beep: check my edited answer with section `Solution2` , here i have added `and Country ='{0}'` to query please check

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi I can not thank you enough, its 1 am here and I have been at this far to long. Thank you once again, works perfect.

Comment: @Beep: no problem :) I'm glad to be help of you :)